# Filtrar datos de una DB, angular y php

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Como puedo filtrar los datos de mi tabla, de acuerdo a un campo o varios campos que ingrese el usuario, con angular y php, hasta el momento lo hago con un pipe, pero lo que busco es que se haga sin tener que cargar todos los datos y después filtrarlos!

Los datos los obtengo de esta forma

```
<?php 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  require("conexion.php"); // IMPORTA EL ARCHIVO CON LA CONEXION A LA DB

  $conexion = conexion(); // CREA LA CONEXION

  // REALIZA LA QUERY A LA DB
  $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM empleados");

  // RECORRE EL RESULTADO Y LO GUARDA EN UN ARRAY
  while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))  
  {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
  }

  $json = json_encode($datos); // GENERA EL JSON CON LOS DATOS OBTENIDOS

  echo $json; // MUESTRA EL JSON GENERADO
?>
```

Alguien podría ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Podrías iterar la cadena de consulta obtenidas con `$_GET` de forma que las añadas a una cadena que se agregaría a la consulta que hacés a la base de datos de forma que quedaría algo así:

```php
<?php 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  require("conexion.php"); // IMPORTA EL ARCHIVO CON LA CONEXION A LA DB

  $where = '';
  foreach($_GET as $k => $v) {
      $where .= "WHERE {$k} = \"{$v}\" AND ";
  }
  $where = rtrim($where, " AND ");

  $conexion = conexion(); // CREA LA CONEXION

  // REALIZA LA QUERY A LA DB
  $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM empleados " . $where);

  // RECORRE EL RESULTADO Y LO GUARDA EN UN ARRAY
  while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))  
  {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
  }

  $json = json_encode($datos); // GENERA EL JSON CON LOS DATOS OBTENIDOS

  echo $json; // MUESTRA EL JSON GENERADO
?>
```

De la anterior forma, si accedes a la URL: `tu.app/api.php?id=1&name=marquez` agregará `WHERE id = "1" AND name = "marquez"` a la consulta.